# Azure DevOps API get test results from a release in a release definition

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a release pipeline setup to run some VSTests. I have the definitionId of the release and wanted to somehow get the test results from this definitionId using Azure DevOps API.

A definitionId has a List of Releases, in which each release can have a list of stages. Each of these different stages run the tests in different environments and output their own results.

definitionId (some release) -> List of Releases -> List of Stages -> Test Results

How can this be done using Azure DevOps API? The List of Releases will be limited to the first 5.

Comment: You can use test runs API and just filter results by time and by release ID
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/runs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#testrun

Comment: @jdfa I believe you need to pass min and max date. The api only allows a 7 day period however which is not long enough. I want all test runs (which is associated to a stage in the release pipeline).

Comment: Actually no, date is optional parameter. I suggest to use it to improve performance but you can go also without it. Do you mean that if you will skip date parameter you will anyway get only results for last 7 days?

Comment: @jdfa no...if i only pass it via release id, it will still return a list of every single testrun (seems like filtering doesn't work)